# How to use refract function of OpenGL ES in 2D?

Tags: android, opengl-es

guys.
I try to apply chromatic aberration effect to my photos. Recently, I knew `refract()` function of OpenGL ES through Googling. And then, I tested it and got a complie error. Here is my fragment shader code.

```
1: vec4 rgbTex;
2: vec2 rVector = refract(baseTexCrd, vec2(0.5, 0.5), 1.1);
3: vec2 gVector = refract(baseTexCrd, vec2(0.5, 0.5), 1.2);
4: vec2 bVector = refract(baseTexCrd, vec2(0.5, 0.5), 1.3);
5: rgbTex.r = vec2(texture2D(imgTex, rVector)).r;
6: rgbTex.g = vec2(texture2D(imgTex, gVector)).g;
7: rgbTex.b = vec2(texture2D(imgTex, bVector)).b;
8: rgbTex.a = 1.0;
9: gl_FragColor = rgbTex;
```

`baseTexCrd` is varying texture coordinates. `imgTex` is my photo texture. And this is an error message about line 7.

```
'b' : vector field selection out of range 
ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

What is wrong? I don't know hot to use it. Especially, in 2D. Please help me. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type `vec2` is a vector with 2 components. The components are `r` and `g` (or `x` and `y`, or `s` and `t`).

So the data type `vec2` has not component `b`, but `vec3` and `vec4` would have a component `b`.
See [Data Type (GLSL) - Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml)

What you want to do is to read the red, green and blue channel of a texuture.
The type of the return value of the GLSL function [**`texture`**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml) is `vec4`, in the case when the type of the texture sampler is *2D*. SO you can access the channels like this:

```
rgbTex.rgb = texture2D(imgTex, rVector).rgb;
```

See the [OpenGL Shading Language 1.20 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.20.pdf)

> **5.5 Vector Components**
>   The names of the components of a vector are denoted by a single letter. As a notational convenience,
>   several letters are associated with each component based on common usage of position, color or texture
>   coordinate vectors. The individual components of a vector can be selected by following the variable
>   name with period ( `.` ) and then the component name.
>   The component names supported are:
>
> `{x, y, z, w}` Useful when accessing vectors that represent points or normals
>
> `{r, g, b, a}` Useful when accessing vectors that represent colors
>
> `{s, t, p, q}` Useful when accessing vectors that represent texture coordinates

Comment: OMG! I was fool! It's a very shamful fault. Thank you very much!